# Checking if a bit is set in ushort (or uchar) in Metal Shader Language

Tags: ios, metal

I have a ushort (or uchar) in MSL (in a fragment shader) and I wonder what is the best performant way to check whether a certain bit is set. Currently, I use e.g. for bit 5 (I start count at 0) in ushort:

```
ushort flags;
bool isBit5Set = (flags & (ushort(1) << 5)) != ushort(0);
```

but I wonder is there some better way that is faster. Thank you for help!